# How to check if a Firebase Snapshot node exists using C#?

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I am working with a Unity application and using Google Firebase, using C#. At one point, I must either edit existing information or add new one. In order to do this I must check if a node exists or not in my snapshot, but I cannot find a function to do so.

HasChild() always returns true, so it's not helpful. I've searched and the function exists() is always mentioned as the best option, but when I try to use it (writing as "exists" or "Exists"), I get the following error:
`error CS1061: Type 'Firebase.Database.DataSnapshot' does not contain a definition for 'Exists' and no extension method 'Exists' of type 'Firebase.Database.DataSnapshot' could be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?` or 
`(...) does not contain a definition for 'exists' (...)`

```
// The data structure looks like:
// .../questions
//      question_0
//          index = 0
//          other information...
//      question_2
//          index = 3
//          other information...
//      question_3
//          index = 5
//          other information...
//      question_6
//          index = 4
//          other information...

// The code I'm using:

public static DataSnapshot dbSnapshot; // I get this from an Event Listener

public void MyMethod(){
    int i = 0;
    bool done = false;
    do {
        string path = "questions/question_" + i.ToString() + "/index";
            if (dbSnapshot.Child(path).Exist()){  // The line that does not work!
            long newValue = (long) dbSnapshot.Child(path).Value;
            // If true, I'll do something here with this value
        } else {
            // If not, I'll do something else here
        }


        // at some point later "done" becomes true, ending loop
        // this part of the code works just fine
    } while (!done);
}
```

Not being able to user Exist(), I tried checking for null values:

```
if (dbSnapshot.Child(path).Value != null)
```

But whenever I hit an question_i that does not exist, I get an error: `InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.` This error does not occur within the if-satament itself, but on the following line. It looks like that ...Value != null is returning true, so on the next line the app tries to get the value, but since it does not exist I get the error.

So, how can I check if a node exists without looking for null values or using Exist() and HasChild() functions?

Comment: Please edit your question to: 1) show how you populate `dbSnapshot`, 2) show what error you get. Also note that the method is called [`Exists()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/database/data-snapshot#exists) with a capital `E`, so calling it any other way won't work.

Comment: I included the 2nd error. I pointed out that I tried to write the method both as 'exists' and 'Exists' (also, as 'exist' and 'Exist') but neither worked. I get the dbSnapshot from an Event Listener that I got from tutorials and it is working fine (in fact, if the node actually exits I can read the data in other parts of the code just fine).